# Copy metadata from one raster to another in rasterio using Python

Tags: python, rasterio, metadata

I have two folders A and B. A contains a raster image with metadata and B contains the same raster images but with data, augmentation applied but with no metadata. One raster image in folder A is augmented 7 times and stored in folder B. I want to copy the metadata from raster folder A into raster B. I have 500 images in folder A

This is what I have tried.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
a = 1
b = 1
while True:
    fp = r"F:\\A\\{}.tif".format(a)
    data = rasterio.open(fp)
    out_meta = data.meta.copy()
    out_transform =  data.transform
    out_height = data.height
    out_width = data.width
    crs = data.crs
    out_meta.update({"driver":"GTiff",
                    "height": out_height,
                     "weight": out_width,
                    "transform": out_transform,
                    "crs" : data.crs })
    out_tif = r'F:\\B\\{}.{}.tif'.format(a,b)
    with rasterio.open(out_tif,"w",**out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_tif)




    a += 1
    b += 1
    if a>500:
        if b > 7:
            break
        break
```

With this code, I get an error

```
InvalidArrayError - Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c8b8395366a1> in <module>
     18     out_tif = r'F:\\B\\{}.{}.tif'.format(a,b)
     19     with rasterio.open(out_tif,"w",**out_meta) as dest:
---> 20         dest.write(out_tif)
     21 
     22     a += 1

rasterio\_io.pyx in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.write()

InvalidArrayError: Positional argument arr must be an array-like object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write file on itself (see comment in code)

```
with rasterio.open(out_tif,"w",**out_meta) as dest:
    # write the file path (a string) to the content of the raster
    # file (it expects the mentioned array-like object from the
    # error), will not work well, hence the error
    dest.write(out_tif)
```

To report metadata, you may try

```
with rasterio.open(out_tif, 'r+') as dest: 
    dest.meta = out_meta
```